# variable indefinida en php

Tags: php

estoy tratando de hacer esta consulta pero siempre al iniciar la pagina me sale el siguiente error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: bpac in C:\xampp\htdocs\AdminLTE\adminlte\index13.php on line 339
```

al parecer la variable no se inicia desde el principio.  alguna ayuda lo agradecería demasiado

```
<?php

                            if(isset($_POST['buscar_pac']))

                                $bpac = trim($_POST['bpac']);


                                $result=mysqli_query($server,"SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cedula LIKE '$bpac''%'");
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                                {




                                    $rn=$row['0'];
                                    if(strlen($rn)==1)
                                    $rn="000".$rn;
                                    elseif(strlen($rn)==2)
                                    $rn="00".$rn;
                                    elseif(strlen($rn)==3)
                                    $rn="0".$rn;
                                    elseif(strlen($rn)>3)
                                    $rn=$rn;

                                    echo"<tr class=odd>
                                        <td>$rn</td>
                                        <td>$row[1]</td>
                                        <td>$row[2]</td>
                                        <td>$row[3]</td>
                                        <td>$row[4]</td>
                                        <td>$row[5]</td>
                                        <td>$row[6]</td>
                                        <td>$row[7]</td>
                                        <td>$row[8]</td>
                                        <td>$row[9]</td>
                                        <td>$row[10]</td>                                                       
                                    </tr>";
                                    echo $msgc;
                                    echo $bpac;
                                }
                        ?>
```

de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vi que el `if` no tenia los corchetes de abierto ni cerrados con el while ni la consulta dentro.

if de la siguiente manera:

```
if (isset($_POST['buscar_pac'])) {

// recoger post, consulta, while, etc.
}
```

Ejemplo con tu código:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['buscar_pac'])) {

    $bpac = trim($_POST['bpac']);

    $result = mysqli_query($server, "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cedula LIKE '$bpac''%'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $rn = $row['0'];
        if (strlen($rn) == 1)
            $rn = "000" . $rn;
        elseif (strlen($rn) == 2)
            $rn = "00" . $rn;
        elseif (strlen($rn) == 3)
            $rn = "0" . $rn;
        elseif (strlen($rn) > 3)
            $rn = $rn;

        echo "<tr class=odd>
        <td>$rn</td>
        <td>$row[1]</td>
        <td>$row[2]</td>
        <td>$row[3]</td>
        <td>$row[4]</td>
        <td>$row[5]</td>
        <td>$row[6]</td>
        <td>$row[7]</td>
        <td>$row[8]</td>
        <td>$row[9]</td>
        <td>$row[10]</td>                                                       
        </tr>";

        echo $msgc;
        echo $bpac;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: GRACIAS  MUCHAS :)

Answer (score 1):

$_POST['bpac'] esta vació agrega un if, en el caso que haya un dato en $_POST['bpac'] continue con la ejecución.

```
if(isset($_POST['buscar_pac'])){
                          if(!isset($_POST['bpac'])){
                                $bpac = trim($_POST['bpac']);


                                $result=mysqli_query($server,"SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cedula LIKE '$bpac''%'");
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                                {




                                    $rn=$row['0'];
                                    if(strlen($rn)==1)
                                    $rn="000".$rn;
                                    elseif(strlen($rn)==2)
                                    $rn="00".$rn;
                                    elseif(strlen($rn)==3)
                                    $rn="0".$rn;
                                    elseif(strlen($rn)>3)
                                    $rn=$rn;

                                    echo"<tr class=odd>
                                        <td>$rn</td>
                                        <td>$row[1]</td>
                                        <td>$row[2]</td>
                                        <td>$row[3]</td>
                                        <td>$row[4]</td>
                                        <td>$row[5]</td>
                                        <td>$row[6]</td>
                                        <td>$row[7]</td>
                                        <td>$row[8]</td>
                                        <td>$row[9]</td>
                                        <td>$row[10]</td>                                                       
                                    </tr>";
                                    echo $msgc;
                                    echo $bpac;
                                }
                           }
```

}
                            ?> ```

Comment: THANKS :) ME DIO IDEA